# Unity's Google VR not viewing stereo

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, google-cardboard, virtual-reality, google-vr-sdk

I want to make game to Google Cardboard using Unity. I downloaded it yesterday, so I think it's the newest version. I downloaded .unitypackage file from https://developers.google.com/vr/unity/download and followed instructions. Still I can not see Cardboard view, when I try to run it. What to do now?

Screenshot:
[image]

The scenes view should look something like this:
[image]

Comment: I'm sorry if this is bad question, but I can not find better Place to ask, or answer.

Comment: At-least, mention your Unity version... Did you even open one of the example scenes?

Comment: Yes I opened sample file. I use Unity 5.6.1f1 Personal on Windows 10.

Comment: What's the name of the sample file? Also please post the screenshot of what you see instead.

Comment: Sample can be found on Assets -> GoogleVR -> Demos -> Scenes and then GVRDemo

Comment: Where I download my screenshot? I can not paste it.

Comment: You said you cannot see Cardboard view. Take screenshot of the game and scene view so that we can what you currently see. You can upload images in your question. Just click the edit button then add the image there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145472/discussion-between-kuvaaja-and-programmer).

Comment: See new image on question and title after it.

Answer (score 0):

The cardboard view is only visible once you build onto a mobile device.

Comment: OK. Thanks. In some YouTube videos it is viewing in preview, or "game" mode. I test it.